# Read files in group and do computation in each group, run on several groups in parallel in DASK

Tags: python, dask

I want to read 100 files corresponding to 100 days data. Every time I read 10 files as a group, for example, day 0-9 as a group, day10-19 as a group, etc, I want to do some computation within each 10-day-group, and lastly aggregate these groups into one dataframe.

I'm new to DASK and not sure whether I make good use of it. Here's my code and is there any possible improvement?

code for generating data (no need for acceleration):

```
import os
import datetime
import dask
df = dask.datasets.timeseries(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-04-11', freq='1d').drop(columns=['name','id'])

if not os.path.exists('data'):
    os.mkdir('data')

def name(i):
    return str(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1) + i * datetime.timedelta(days=1))

df.to_csv('data/*.csv', name_function=name)
```

code for data processing:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

N_FILES = 100
GROUP_SIZE = 10
CORR_WINDOW = 5
start_date = date(2022, 1, 1)


# calculate correlation of two series
def rolling_corr(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series, window: int) -> pd.Series:
    return s1.rolling(window=window).corr(other=s2)


# delayed, read one file
@dask.delayed
def read_file(filename: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(filename)


# delayed, read several files in parallel and compute correlation
@dask.delayed
def read_and_cal_corr(start_date: date, ndays: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df_ls = []
    cur_date = start_date
    for _ in range(ndays):
        df = read_file(f'./data/{str(cur_date)}.csv')
        df_ls.append(df)
        cur_date += timedelta(days=1)
    df_ls = dask.compute(df_ls)[0]
    df = pd.concat(df_ls)
    df['corr'] = rolling_corr(df['x'], df['y'], CORR_WINDOW)
    return df


# main, call read_and_cal_corr() on each group and aggregate results
df_ls = []
cur_date = start_date
for _ in range(N_FILES // GROUP_SIZE):
    df = read_and_cal_corr(cur_date, GROUP_SIZE)
    cur_date += timedelta(days=GROUP_SIZE)
    df_ls.append(df)

df_ls = dask.compute(df_ls)[0]
result = pd.concat(df_ls)
print(result)
```

Comment: Why do you select only the first element? `df_ls = dask.compute(df_ls)[0]` this would return only a single dataframe even after computing all of them

Comment: Also it seems like rolling_corr is going to roll by 5 rows, not 5 days. Don’t you just want to compute the full correlation coefficient (a constant) for each group of 5 dfs? So this wouldn’t be anything rolled.

Comment: If each group of 10 dfs is small enough to fit into memory I wouldn’t mess with dask inside your loop. Just compute the 10-day partition using pandas only. Then you can stitch the partition futures together using `result = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(df_ls)`